# android from activity to fragment

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview, android-fragments

I'm new to android. I want to put one of the activity under one of the tab of my app(the tab is fragment) when i paste my code into fragment, there's a lot of error...

There's error in new JSONParse().execute();  It shows that the type JSONParse is not visible.

in this line private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask  there's error 
showing illegal modifier for the class JSONParse.only public, abstract and final are permitted.

this line pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TabActivityQueue.this);  it shows the constructor progressDialog is undefined.

All the variables phonenumber, peoplenumber , remarks, status, table2, url    are not resolved as variables.

What should I change? I'm really stuck.

Here's the activity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
TextView number;
TextView info;
TextView remark;
TextView statuss;
Button Btngetdata;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://172.22.85.235:8080/Qproject/servlet/Qaction?action_flag=find";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String Table2 = "table2";
private static final String phonenumber = "phonenumber";
private static final String peoplenumber = "peoplenumber";
private static final String remarks = "remarks";
private static final String status = "status";

JSONArray table2 = null;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             new JSONParse().execute();


        }
    });


}



private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         number = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number);
         info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
         remark = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.remark);
         statuss = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.statuss);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();



    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                table2 = json.getJSONArray(Table2);
                for(int i = 0; i < table2.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = table2.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String number = c.getString(phonenumber);
                String info = c.getString(peoplenumber);
                String remark = c.getString(remarks);
                String statuss = c.getString(status);




                // Adding value HashMap key => value


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(phonenumber, number);
                map.put(peoplenumber, info);
                map.put(remarks, remark);
                map.put(status, statuss);

                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { phonenumber,peoplenumber, remarks,status }, new int[] {
                                R.id.number,R.id.info, R.id.remark,R.id.statuss});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     }
}
```

Here's the fragment where i pasted the activity code in :

```
public class TabActivityQueue extends Fragment {

ListView list;
TextView number;
TextView info;
TextView remark;
TextView statuss;
Button Btngetdata;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//URL to get JSON Array
public static String url = "http://172.22.85.235:8080/Qproject/servlet/Qaction?action_flag=find";

//JSON Node Names 
public static final String Table2 = "table2";
public static final String phonenumber = "phonenumber";
public static final String peoplenumber = "peoplenumber";
public static final String remarks = "remarks";
public static final String status = "status";

JSONArray table2 = null;



 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            //This layout contains your list view 
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_activity_queue, container, false);

                oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                number = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number);
             info = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.info);
             remark = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.remark);
             statuss = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.statuss);


                Btngetdata = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.getdata);
                Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                         new JSONParse().execute();


                    }
                });

             return view;
        }
      }
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();

   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TabActivityQueue.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
   pDialog.show();



}

@Override
   protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
     pDialog.dismiss();
     try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            table2 = json.getJSONArray(Table2);
            for(int i = 0; i < table2.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = table2.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String number = c.getString(phonenumber);
            String info = c.getString(peoplenumber);
            String remark = c.getString(remarks);
            String statuss = c.getString(status);




            // Adding value HashMap key => value


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(phonenumber, number);
            map.put(peoplenumber, info);
            map.put(remarks, remark);
            map.put(status, statuss);

            oslist.add(map);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { phonenumber,peoplenumber, remarks,status }, new int[] {
                            R.id.number,R.id.info, R.id.remark,R.id.statuss});

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class TabActivityQueue extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    TextView number;
    TextView info;
    TextView remark;
    TextView statuss;
    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // URL to get JSON Array
    public static String url = "http://172.22.85.235:8080/Qproject/servlet/Qaction?action_flag=find";

    // JSON Node Names
    public static final String Table2 = "table2";
    public static final String phonenumber = "phonenumber";
    public static final String peoplenumber = "peoplenumber";
    public static final String remarks = "remarks";
    public static final String status = "status";

    JSONArray table2 = null;

    private Activity activity;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // This layout contains your list view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_activity_queue, container, false);

        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
        info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
        remark = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remark);
        statuss = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statuss);

        Btngetdata = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();

            }
        });

        activity = this.getActivity();
        return view;
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                table2 = json.getJSONArray(Table2);
                for (int i = 0; i < table2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = table2.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                    String number = c.getString(phonenumber);
                    String info = c.getString(peoplenumber);
                    String remark = c.getString(remarks);
                    String statuss = c.getString(status);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(phonenumber, number);
                    map.put(peoplenumber, info);
                    map.put(remarks, remark);
                    map.put(status, statuss);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(activity, oslist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {phonenumber, peoplenumber, remarks, status}, new int[] {R.id.number, R.id.info,
                            R.id.remark, R.id.statuss});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereever you have used context as TabActivityQueue.this (or getApplicationCOntext()) change to getActivity() .

Also if some android pre defined method doesn't work try prefix getActivity() like:- getActivity().method();

Answer (score 0):

declare `private Activity activity` as `public Activity activity;`